# QuickFIX Initiator sends logout request and does not reconnect

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am using a FIX session to get TradeCaptureReports. When connection is established, I get responses to TradeCaptureRequest. After logon, heartbeat messages are sending and receiving.

But then FIX initiator sends logout request and does not reconnect, even if ReconnectInterval is set to 1 in session config.

event log:

```
08:23:56 : Initiated logon request
08:23:56 : Logon contains ResetSeqNumFlag=Y, reseting sequence numbers to 1
08:23:56 : Received logon response
08:25:42 : Initiated logout request
```

I need to keep QuickFIX connection alive and keep sending scheduled TradeCaptureRequests. Do you have any idea, what can cause this logout?

---

Message log after logon request and response:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=56|35=0|34=3|49=**|52=20151203-08:24:56.310|56=***|10=169|
8=FIX.4.4|9=56|35=0|49=***|56=**|34=3|52=20151203-08:24:55.771|10=179|
8=FIX.4.4|9=56|35=0|34=4|49=**|52=20151203-08:25:26.313|56=***|10=171|
8=FIX.4.4|9=56|35=0|49=***|56=**|34=4|52=20151203-08:25:25.772|10=179|
8=FIX.4.4|9=56|35=5|34=5|49=**|52=20151203-08:25:42.338|56=***|10=182|
```

Session Config:

```
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=1
ResetOnLogon=Y
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual FIX messages that lead up to the logout. My advice: look for a good FIX log viewer and analyze the FIX log file for indications as to the cause. If that doesn't help you, you could ask your couterparty; maybe they have better insight.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the relevant FIX messages here (by editing your question, pasting the relevant FIX messages in a code block). Replace the SOH character by a printable character like the pipe symbol `|`.

Comment: @TT All I can see from the messages is that a healthy connection is getting killed by the initiator itself somehow :) Even though session gets disconnected, it has to try to reconnect right?

Comment: `ReconnectInterval` should probably be 30 (I have never seen it set to 1).

Comment: The FIX messages don't give an indication why this is happening. Maybe you could put a break in your `Application` instance to see what initiated the logout?

Comment: Excuse me... did you find the reason? I experienced same issue when initiator was disconnected and performs no attempts to reconnect again. But it was once for now (i.e. not repeating behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

I won't be able to test this until Monday, but I don't think you can set your StartTime to be equal to your EndTime.  That would explain why it's disconnecting, because it doesn't think it's time for the session to be up.

QuickFix does support week long sessions, if you use the StartDay and EndDay parameters, in conjunction with the StartTime and EndTime ones.